# Microstrategy Enterprise manager upgrade

Tags: microstrategy

I have been upgrading Microstrategy from version 9.2 to 10.3 and facing difficulties in upgrading the enterprise manager project. is there anyone who has done this and can help me with the approach.

Answer (score 1):

INTRODUCTION

Enterprise Manager 10.x is not dependent on Operations Manager and Health Center and can be controlled through MicroStrategy Command Manager. The operations that can be performed from Operations Manager > Enterprise Manager such as creating environment, creating data load and running data load etc., can now be done through Command Manager.

The PDF Document attached at the end of this Technical Document covers all the different configurations and actions that can be performed in Enterprise Manager 10.x by using its respective Command Manager Scripts.
[MicroStrategy EM 10.3 Whats New](https://community.microstrategy.com/mxret26282/attachments/mxret26282/server/5259/1/What%20is%20new%20in%20Enterprise%20Manager%2010.2.pdf)